# Error parsing date for X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to parse data from json data in D3.js, here is the problem function.

```
minDate = new Date(data[0][0]);
    maxDate = new Date(data[274][0]); 

var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain([minDate, maxDate])
      .range([0, width]);
```

Here is the error

```
Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"
```

The CodePen link https://codepen.io/rocket18/pen/qpVeBj

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were just some minor issues, you used `d3.timeFormat` instead of `d3.timeParse`, I added `d.year = parseDate(d[0]);` in the `data.forEach` and you appended an svg element to a svg element, I changed it to a div instead.

I also used `d3.extent` in the `.domain`

Here's the full working code: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OQxA2af1BuuhCOGexo6U?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks so much! I have not been using d3 very long and did not know about that function.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code I see that when you create the x scale function that you call `x`

```
var x =  d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([0, width]);
```

`minDate` and `maxDate` are no more `Date` object because you did this

```
minDate = parse(minDate);
maxDate = parse(maxDate);
```

try defining the x function before.

Comment: Thanks for the assist but @Robert Anderson had the best answer for me.